# CkEditor5 and CKFinder

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckfinder, ckfinder3

Really basic question I hope.

I keep getting a 'no upload adapter' error message in the console when I try to add an image using CKeditor 5 - Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter

Below are the instructions from the documentation.

*Configuring the image upload only
This feature can upload images automatically to the server (e.g. when the image is dropped into the content) thanks to the CKFinder upload adapter. All it requires is the correct config.ckfinder.uploadUrl path.
Assuming that the CKFinder PHP server-side connector is installed (available) under https://example.com/ckfinder/, use the following quick upload command URL to enable the image upload:*

```
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ CKFinder, ... ],

        // Enable the "Insert image" button in the toolbar.
        toolbar: [ 'uploadImage', ... ],

        ckfinder: {
            // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
           uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php? command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
        }
    } )
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... );
```

I have added the above code onto the webpage where my editor exists within  tags. Am I doing this wrong? Should this code be added somewhere else, within the config file somewhere else I am missing?

Link to the documentation in question - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/ckfinder.html

The uploader works fine if I go to the sample page - http://example.com/ckfinder/samples/full-page-open.html

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get this working, so used https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package instead.